# consuming Java web services. Issues with id session

Tags: java, web-services, api, authentication

i am having some issues and almost no documentation on internet about id session tokens and Java web services. We have a server (Tomcat providing web services on JAX-WS + SOAP) that is providing an API to query an SQL server.

I have to code a simple Java client that communicates with the server through this web services. The issue is that before being able to use any of its server WSDL methods, the client has to authenticate through a web server method where you send the user/pass, and the server gives back to client a session-id (alfanumeric string).

The rest of the methods do not have any kind of parameter where i can pass the session id, so i suppose it has to be used as a "context". I have found information about how in JAX-WS you can maintain session-id:

https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2006/06/maintaining_ses.html

```
Hello port = new HelloService().getHelloPort();
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.
SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY,true);
```

in my case, if i want to receive the cookie session-id, i have to:

```
org.tempuri.RUWebService service = new org.tempuri.RUWebService();
org.tempuri.RUWebServiceSoap myport = new org.tempuri.RUWebServiceSoap();
String session-id = myport.Auth(user,pass);
```

where the session-id is an UUID variable is a String of a hex variable: 8-4-4-4-8 .. that i can change to real hex like:

```
java.util.UUID uuidFromHyphens = java.util.UUID.fromString("6f34f25e-0b0d-4426-8ece-a8b3f27f4b63");
```

I tried the following code, where i change "port" variable to "myport", trying to match both examples:

```
((BindingProvider)myport).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.
SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY,true);
```

It compiles, but when i consult the web server through some of its methods, i receive a "null", the same as if i do not make the auth procedure. **My issue i think is that i don't know what i am doing wrong with cookie session-id auth procedure.**

If somebody could help me, i would be grateful.

regards.

Answer (score 1):

Either you pass it as `Request Parameter` using GET or POST methods

(or)

Put the session id in outgoing HTTP header, like

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Accept: text/plain
Accept: text/html
Session-Id:DFF55566_SOMEID
```

But for both of this to work, your web server must expect the `Session Id` from client in some format either at server level (or) your application level.

Comment: Hi K139,thank you very much for your answer.I understand that the sessionID has to travel in some way, but my issue is how.I created a client project in NetBeans as a "Web Service Client" so that i can access to server API methods like they were in local, but not in low level were you can manipulate GET and POST.So my doubt is still active: How can i send the sessionID with the method to the server in Java? thanks in advance.